# PostgreSQL вставить значение в каждый элемент массива JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Есть следующий массив типа JSONB

```
[{"Price": 1494.0, "SkuId": 749802, "Quantity": 8}, 
{"Price": 4415.0, "SkuId": 2009534, "Quantity": 3}, 
{"Price": 4674.0, "SkuId": 1081083, "Quantity": 2}]
```

Необходимо в каждый элемент массива добавить OrderId.
Должен работать следующий запрос

```
select  
    jsonb_insert('[{"Price": 1494.0, "SkuId": 749802, "Quantity": 8},
      {"Price": 4415.0, "SkuId": 2009534, "Quantity": 3},
      {"Price": 4674.0, "SkuId": 1081083, "Quantity": 2}]', CAST('{[0, 1], Order_Id}' as text[]), to_jsonb(3), true);
```

Однако, он выдаёт ошибку [22P02] ERROR: path element at position 1 is not an integer: "[*]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonb_insert обновляет только один элемент, т.к. json не гарантирует, что все элементы могут быть одинаковы, напр. `[{"a"1}, 5, "ttt"]`
Если нужно обновить только одну строку:

```
select jsonb_insert ('[{"Price": 1494.0, "SkuId": 749802, "Quantity": 8},
      {"Price": 4415.0, "SkuId": 2009534, "Quantity": 3}]' :: jsonb,
     '{0,OrderId}'::text[] , '0'::jsonb, false);
```

На выходе, у первого элемента добавится OrderId, а у последующих нет: `[{"Price": 1494.0, "SkuId": 749802, "OrderId": 0, "Quantity": 8}, {"Price": 4415.0, "SkuId": 2009534, "Quantity": 3}]`

Для обновления каждого элемента, можно разбить массив на отдельные элементы, и у каждого объекта json добавить нужное поле через оператор `||` , а затем объединить:

```
select jsonb_agg( t.j || '{"OrderId": 8}'::jsonb) from
    (select jsonb_array_elements ('
     [{"Price": 1494.0, "SkuId": 749802, "Quantity": 8},
      {"Price": 4415.0, "SkuId": 2009534, "Quantity": 3},
      {"Price": 4674.0, "SkuId": 1081083, "Quantity": 2}]' :: jsonb) as j ) t;
```